# How to have ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Checkboxfor as checked by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkboxfor

I want mt view to have the check box checked by default,
I tried something like this.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.GenericsOK, new { id = ViewBag.GenericsOK, @checked = true })
```

and also

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.GenericsOK, new { id = ViewBag.GenericsOK, @checked = "checked"})
```

in both cased it give the below error.
**String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.**

My property is defined as this.

```
private bool _deafaultchecked = true;

    [Display(Name = "Generics Ok")]
    public bool GenericsOK
    {
        get { return _deafaultchecked; }
        set { _deafaultchecked = value; }
    }
```

any suggestions please?

---

---

Since i could not find a solution or this.
i got this done like this.

```
 @Html.CheckBox("GenericsOK", true, new {id=ViewBag.GenericsOK, name="GenericsOK" })
```

this works for my requirement.
thanks for all who helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to remove the @checked="checked" portion of the HTML attributes.  If the viewmodel property is a boolean then it is unnecessary when you use the CheckBoxFor

Answer (score 1):

In your controller's Create method (I presume), have you tried this?

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new YourModelClass { GenericsOk = true });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action where you create the model just set that field value to true.

For example

```
return View(new DriverCsvModel{SendEmails = true});
```

You should be using the state of the model, rather than forcing the UI into a checked state.

Answer (score 0):

In the default constructor for your model class, you can set the "GenericsOK" property to "True"

Comment: Justin, I have done that, please see the edit in my question. and correct me if i am missing anything. thanks